# use of deprecated item 'std::ascii::AsciiExt': use inherent methods instead

Tags: rust

I wrote this

```
let somestring = "hello happy haddock hahaha".to_string();
let mut freq: HashMap<char, u32> = HashMap::new();
for c in somestring.chars() {                                                                                       
    let c = AsciiExt::to_ascii_lowercase(&c);
    *freq.entry(c).or_insert(0) += 1;
}
```

then I got this

```
warning: use of deprecated item 'std::ascii::AsciiExt': use inherent methods instead
--> src/main.rs:2:5
  |
2 | use std::ascii::AsciiExt;
  |     ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^
  |
  = note: `#[warn(deprecated)]` on by default

warning: use of deprecated item 'std::ascii::AsciiExt::to_ascii_lowercase': use inherent methods instead
 --> src/main.rs:8:11
  |
8 |     let c1 = AsciiExt::to_ascii_lowercase(&c);
  |              ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^
```

The following conversion works without a warning, but it's much slower than `to_ascii_lowercase()`.

```
let c = c.to_lowercase().collect::<Vec<_>>()[0];
```

I only have ASCII letters in the `somestring` variable. What should I do to convert them to lower case?

Thank you for answering to this question! Here is a link to the code.

https://play.rust-lang.org/?version=stable&mode=debug&edition=2018&gist=7612f6a78520ec3f1457454f0e5cf36f

Comment: It's hard to answer your question because it doesn't include a [MRE]. We can't tell what crates (and their versions), types, traits, fields, etc. are present in the code. It would make it easier for us to help you if you try to reproduce your error on the [Rust Playground](https://play.rust-lang.org) if possible, otherwise in a brand new Cargo project, then [edit] your question to include the additional info. There are [Rust-specific MRE tips](//stackoverflow.com/tags/rust/info) you can use to reduce your original code for posting here. Thanks!

Comment: Answers have been given below. The reason `to_lowercase().collect::<Vec_>>()[0]` is slower (as you said) is that you are iterating over the chars that constitute the lowercase version of whatever was the original char, collect all of them into a Vec and then take the first char in that Vec. That's a lot of work. It is also wrong: As the docs for `to_lowercase` say, a unicode-char may need more than one char in its lowercase representation. If you *know* that you are dealing with ascii (hint: really? REALLY?), you can use `to_ascii_lowercase`.

Answer (score 1):

As the message states, use the inherent methods (like [`char::to_ascii_lowercase`](https://doc.rust-lang.org/std/primitive.char.html#method.to_ascii_lowercase) instead of the trait methods:

```rust
use std::collections::HashMap;

fn main() {
    let somestring = "hello happy haddock hahaha".to_string();
    let mut freq: HashMap<char, u32> = HashMap::new();
    for c in somestring.chars() {
        let c = c.to_ascii_lowercase();
        *freq.entry(c).or_insert(0) += 1;
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Remove the `use std::ascii:AsciiExt;` line.

[`str::to_ascii_lowercase`](https://doc.rust-lang.org/std/primitive.str.html#method.to_ascii_lowercase) has been stable since v1.23.0.

Comment: There is no `use std::ascii:AsciiExt` line in the provided code.

Comment: True, I based the answer on the warning which reports it in their source at `src/main.rs:2:5`.

Answer (score 1):

You could use `char::to_ascii_lowercase` and leverage the fact that `somestring.chars()` returns an iterator:

```
use std::collections::HashMap;

fn main() {
    let somestring = "hello happy haddock hahaha".to_string();
    let mut freq: HashMap<char, u32> = HashMap::new();
    for c in somestring.chars().map(|ch: char| ch.to_ascii_lowercase()) {
        *freq.entry(c).or_insert(0) += 1;
    }

    println!("{:?}", freq)
}
```

Output:

```
{'a': 5, 'y': 1, 'l': 2, 'h': 6, 'e': 1, 'o': 2, 'c': 1, ' ': 3, 'p': 2, 'd': 2, 'k': 1}
```

[Playground](https://play.rust-lang.org/?version=stable&mode=debug&edition=2018&gist=66237ea5b24dc82926c8b1f9c85f53fc)